# Tensorflow Object Detection API: disable nonmaxima suppression for off-the-shelf models

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Is it possible and/or easy to disable the non-maxima suppression part of the off-the-shelf object detectors provided in the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection)? E.g., I'd like to run the provided "SSD mobilenet which was trained on MSCOCO" without the non-maxima operation at the end. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this for speed reasons, the only way is to edit the code itself (see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L331) --- this is a bit involved as you need to replace the call to NMS by code that would still put the boxes in the expected output format.

If you just want to get rid of the effect of NMS, you can simply set the score_threshold and iou_threshold of the postprocessing part of the config file:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config#L131 
to be 0.0 and 1.0 respectively, meaning, don't filter low scoring boxes, and prune boxes based on iou only if they perfectly overlap (which in practice will be never).

Comment: Changing the config sounds good but will it affect how a saved model (e.g. ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017) runs?   I wan to run the off-the-shelf ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017. Which config file should I change so that NMS effect is simply removed?

Comment: So the "off-the-shelf" frozen models that we provide will not be changed if you just change the config --- meaning that they will continue to use the old NMS parameters.  If you want to regenerate those off-the-shelf .pb files, you can change the config file then re-export using the export_inference_graph.py script.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have to export new pb files. It would be perfect if I can  (i) import the SSD frozen model, (ii) change its config, i.e. NMS parameters, and (iii) run the SSD model with the config. Now I know how to handle step (ii), I need help with steps (i) and (iii).

Comment: I would also need the config file for ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017 which seems to be not included in the repo. Without this file, what you suggested is not doable, I guess.

Comment: Oh, you should be able to just modify the pets config file here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config --- you will need to replace the Pets labelmap with an appropriate COCO labelmap and change the number of output classes.  (But nothing else)

Comment: @JonathanHuang Could you explain more on the first option of removing the call to nms? I'm guessing that call is happening here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L779
I'm just not sure what's next after removing it, can I just re-export the model after that change?

On the second option, it seems that changing the config will only remove the effects, but the computation is still being done, correct?